# Is it Possible to Grab Historical Config Data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am looking to conduct metrics on my AWS Config Rules (i.e, see how Compliance Status has changed over time) and I have been unable to determine the best way to do this.

In the aggregated rule panel within the console, you can only see current compliance status, not historical data.

I've also looked at the Boto3 API and can not determine which function calls would provide me with compliance data for a particular Config Rule.

Has anyone else jumped this hurdle, or have any ideas as to where I should look to create my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historical data over rule compliance changes is currently not directly available.

One way to track the compliance changes of your rules is to [monitor your rules with CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/monitor-config-with-cloudwatchevents.html).

[image]

With a Lambda function as target that calls [PutMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html) ([`put_metric_data`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data)) to [publish a custom metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html), you should be able to track over time.

You can also have a Lambda run [DescribeComplianceByConfigRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeComplianceByConfigRule.html) ([`describe_compliance_by_config_rule`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.describe_compliance_by_config_rule)) and publish data to a custom metric periodically.

Comment: Thank you so much that was incredibly helpful! Already implemented in my sandbox account!